# Deleted the postfix folder, now what?

Tags: 14.04, postfix

Postfix wasn't working right. So I uninstalled it using `apt-get remove` and `apt-get remove --purge` .. but whenever I'd reinstall it, it would never show the configuration screen. So I deleted the entire `/etc/postfix` folder. Sure enough, the next time I installed it, the config screen showed up. I went ahead and completed the configuration etc.

Problem is, I expected the `/etc/postfix` directory to be restored, but it's not there.

Now what?

Comment: Did you try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The folder `/etc/postfix` **is** part of the package `postfix`

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall postfix
```

To reconfigure `postfix`

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

---

```
$ apt-file search --regex "^/etc/postfix/"
postfix: /etc/postfix/post-install
postfix: /etc/postfix/postfix-files
postfix: /etc/postfix/postfix-script
```